Can I apply the modulation property of Fourier Transform on sine?
Modulation property of Fourier Transform:
\begin{align}
x(t) \cos(\omega_0 t) \longrightarrow \frac{1}{2} \left[ X(\omega - \omega_0) + X(\omega + \omega_0) \right]
\end{align}
Can I not apply it if my cosine has a phase shift?
I am asking this because I am solving this problem:
\begin{align} 
x(t)\sin(10\pi t)
\end{align}
to
\begin{align} 
x(t)\cos(10\pi t + \frac \pi 2)
\end{align}
Then apply modulation

The reason you're getting negative votes is that this question demonstrates that you're not really cracking the textbook.  You have to ask yourself why $$x(t) \cos(\omega_0 t) \longleftrightarrow \tfrac{1}{2} \big( X(\omega - \omega_0) + X(\omega + \omega_0) \big)$$
When you understand why that is true, you can apply exactly the same thinking with $x(t) \sin(\omega_0 t)$.

I asked this question because I did not see an equivalent identity for sine on the fourier transform property table, I was confused because It seemed that it can be applied, so I came here to see if there was somehting I did not notice.

yes, you can apply it exactly the same.
To see that, use the complex sinusoidal representation of the cosine, and try to represent your phase shift as factor (that doesn't depend on $t$) that you pull "in front" of the cosine.
